# Text manipulation with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have bash variables defined in some file:

```
VAR1=....
VAR2="some value"
VAR3=....
....
```

How can I change the value of some variable and add one more variable in the specific line? I need to do it in the single shell script.

**EDIT:**

Expected output is:

```
VAR1=....
VAR2="another value"
VAR3=....
NEW_VAR=....
....
```

Comment: Please add your desired output to your question.

Comment: Post is edited.

Comment: Let me understand. You have a bash-file (or any another text file) which contain number of strings. And you want to update this script (or text-file). Correct?

Comment: Yes, I have bash variable declarations in the file, and I want to change variable values and add additional variables on the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following code would achieve the results you want, if I understood your question correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash

#change the value of a certain variable
sed -i -e 's/^VAR2=.*$/VAR2="another-value"/gi' /folder/file

#add a new variable to the variable declaration area, using one existing variable as a reference point
sed -i -e '/^VAR2=/i \NEW_VAR="another-value"' /folder/file

exit 0
```

That would substitute the value of a variable and add a new variable to the list using one existing variable as the reference point as to where to insert the new variable. This code would work in many Bash versions.

Comment: Thanks for solution! One more question: How I cold enhance to replace value of second occurrence of VAR2?

Comment: The way I would go to solve this (change VAR in other occurrences) is to put a comment by each occurrence of the VAR and then use sed to identify the occurrence based on the comment. For example (of commenting): VAR="some-value" #1st -occurrence-var